# Athenticating gcloud service account within gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am deploying a service to gcloud from gitlab-ci.yml file using gcloud-service-key.json. I get this error

> $ google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file
> ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json ERROR: gcloud crashed (ValueError): No
> key could be detected.

Find below a subset of the code snippet

```css
 - apk add --update make ca-certificates openssl python --repository https://alpine.global.ssl.fastly.net/alpine/v3.10/community --repository https://alpine.global.ssl.fastly.net/alpine/v3.10/main && rm -fR /var/cache/apk/*
  - update-ca-certificates
  # Write our GCP service account private key into a file
  - echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
  # Download and install Google Cloud SDK
  - wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
  - tar zxvf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=false --path-update=true
  - google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud --quiet components update
  - google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
```

Any help will be appraciated, I've been at this for several days now.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there's an issue with you key-file. Try generating new one with gcloud:

```
$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key1.json --iam-account=test123@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
created key [6ca5ffc929f31d1f1915d430887a7fa3689eb69d] of type [json] as [key1.json] for [test123@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

There's also an [official documentation how to generate a key](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/create) - feel free to have a look if in doubt.

Your `json` key-file should look like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxxxx,
  "private_key_id": "6ca5ffc929f31d1f1915d430887a7fa3689eb69d",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAsdfsd234fesSiAgEAAoIBAQDKnmI67Aw3DgHM\n1b25LH1jRAV0pt6hjTEeJGH$
  "client_email": "test123@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "110107674812168412361",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/test123@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

If your file looks in a different way check the `echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json` part. It may be an issue with the `$GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY` variable.

Also if you have any doubts about activating an account there's also [another piece of documentation on how to do it](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account).